# What is the correct way to say the next sentence?

Tags: grammar

Spanish is my first language and I just saw a post on Instagram that says "Quality sobriety must include self acceptance" and I want to comment it by saying this:

This is the hardest part for me

Is it correct?

Comment: I think we use "this" less powerfully than you use "esto."  Maybe that's because you have "este" and "esta" to deal with nouns, leaving "esto" free to refer to the concept in the sentence to which it refers.  In English, I think it would be best to say "The self-acceptance" is the hardest part for me.